# Wrong value with double.Parse(string)

Tags: .net, parsing, double

I'm trying to convert a string to a double value in .Net 3.5. Quite easy so far with

```
double.Parse(value);
```

My problem is that values with exponential tags are not right converted.
Example:

```
double value = double.Parse("8.493151E-2");
```

The value should be = 0.0893151 right?
But it isn't!
The value is = 84931.51!!!

How can that be?
I'm totally confused!

I read the reference in the msdn library and it confirms that values like "8.493151E-2" are supported. I also tried overloads of double.Parse() with NumberStyles, but no success.

Please help!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It works for me:

```
double.Parse("8.493151E-2");  
0.08493151
```

---

You're probably running in a locale that uses `,` for the decimal separator and `.` for the thousands separator.
Therefore, it's being treated as `8,493,151E-2`, which is in fact equivalent to `84,931.51`.

Change it to

```
double value = double.Parse("8.493151E-2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Ok, that works!
I didn't try to use it with IFormatProvider
Thanks!

Comment: @flashfail - if you don't specify an `IFormatProvider` it will use your computer's locale. You give your location as "DE Oldenburg", which I'm assuming is in Germany - where you use a decimal comma and "." as the thousands separator.